# Batch Script to copy new files only

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, batch-file, echo

I have a small batch script to move files from shared to location to my E-drive. The script below moves the file from the shared location and deletes it from the shared location.

```
@echo off
cls

NET USE Q: \\lMC-Wheat-tick\PQ120R2A3 /USER:SAPQMPQ-LOCAL\USername       "Password"

move "Q:\*.csv" "E:\CSV Files\CSV\CSVSource\"

NET USE Q: /DELETE /Y
echo on
```

I want to modify this code not to delete the file in shared location and pick only the files from the shared location that are not in my E-Drive ("E:\CSV Files\CSV\CSVSource\").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you not add any date params have you tried a google search.. also can you write / create a windows service that has an FileWatcher to do this..?

Comment: Read the documentation for `ROBOCOPY`, it should have the features to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls

NET USE Q: \\lMC-Wheat-tick\PQ120R2A3 /USER:SAPQMPQ-LOCAL\USername       "Password"

echo n|copy /-Y "Q:\*.csv" "E:\CSV Files\CSV\CSVSource\"

echo on
```

-Y prompts before overwriting and you can pipe n to all those questions. So this would in essence just copy non-existing files.